# Что такое CursorTreeAdapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter, cursoradaper

Почитал документ, но так и не понял, что такое `CursorTreeAdapter`. Что-то вроде реализации `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, которое содержит какие-то курсоры. Кто-то знает, что это такое?

Comment: сам только взялся учить андроид, то очень по простому, адаптер - это такая фигня, которая привязывает представление к данным, от сюда вывод, что CursorTreeAdapter - привязывает данные к виду виндовс-проводника.

Comment: Что такое адаптер в общем, я знаю. И несколько раз использовал разные адаптеры: для `Spinner, AutoCompleteTextView, ListView`, и т.д. Мне непонятно, именно этот адаптер для чего.

Comment: практика все объяснила бы. но это только для избранных. а для обычного человека обучение - это зубрежка и размышления на пустом месте